Number next to a capturing group
This is my input:
zone-1
zone-2
zone-3

I want to replace
zone\-\d+

to:
zone-5

This is my attempt:
var zones = new string[]
{
    "zone-1",
    "zone-2",
    "zone-3"
};

var r = new Regex(@"(zone-)(\d+)");

foreach (var zone in zones)
{
    var newZone = r.Replace(zone, "$15");
    Console.WriteLine(newZone);
}

It doesn't work, because $15 means to capture group 15. I want to capture group 1 and concatenate 5. How can I do that?

you could use the Replace callback and then get the match.Groups[1].Value and prepend that before the 5

r.Replace(zone, "${1}5"), see the answer.

Why to you need a capture group at all? Just replace zone-\d+ with zone-5
